# What is the need of having a key schedule before executing AES

Tags: aes

Can someone explain to me why does using a key schedule make's AES more secure if instead of calculating and adding your round key's, you just keep on adding the cipher key. ?

Comment: Well, how would AES-256 work without a key-schedule?

Comment: Instead of calculating and adding your round key's, you just keep on adding the cypher key.

Comment: How would you do that with a 256-bit key on 128-bit blocks? (or even better with AES-192 with 192-bit keys on 128-bit blocks)

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer, I see what you mean now. But say, I have a 128-bit key on 128-bit blocks, what would the use of the schedule be?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How secure would AES be with all round keys equal?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/63864/18298), [AES and DES - reusing the same round keys](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/63629/aes-and-des-reusing-the-same-round-keys), [Why do block ciphers use key schedules instead of round constants? (Even-Mansour)](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/62062/why-do-block-ciphers-use-key-schedules-instead-of-round-constants-even-mansour),

Comment: and [Security of key schedule that only XORs a key with constants](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/52278/security-of-key-schedule-that-only-xors-a-key-with-constants)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AES and DES - reusing the same round keys](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/63629/aes-and-des-reusing-the-same-round-keys)

Answer (score 4):

Not using separate keys for each AES round would make your cipher vulnerable to slide attacks.
Using two plaintexts M and M' with M' being the result of an AES round after calculating M as input, you can differentiate between those plaintexts by calculating the output of an AES round which takes the ciphertext C as input.

Due to the birthday problem, this attack schould reduce the complexity of breaking the AES to $\mathcal{O}(2^{n/2})$.

Source: [Silde attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slide_attack)

Answer (score 2):

Many block ciphers, including AES, encrypt using multiple/iterated rounds (10, 12 or 14 for AES depending on key size). Each round requires a key, called sub-key or round key (always 128-bit for AES), and it would be a weakness¹ if the same sub-key was used at each round.

The key schedule's job is to expand the original key (128, 192 or 256-bit for AES) into one sub-key per round. Without somewhat executing the key schedule, we would not get the right sub-keys, and the result of AES encryption or decryption would be wrong.

The key schedule does not really need to be performed *before executing AES*, at least for encryption: it can be performed *while* executing AES, and that's pretty common in hardware, and even in software when speed is less important than key ability and memory size.

---

¹ This other [answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/79803/555) gives an attack, I would not bet there are not others even for AES-128, and for larger key sizes much of the key bits would go unused.

PS: much of the question is about the reasons for multiple subkeys, thus my answer is lacking; upvote another!

Comment: " it would be a weakness if the same sub-key was used at each round." <- I think the OP is interested in said weakness

Comment: @SEJPM: yes, but something comprehensive on this would make the answer may times bigger, even if I stick to AES; and I'm not sure how I would start.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the subkey derivation during each  round rather than all at once.